# :key attribute on parent router-view causes leave (out) transition to fail in nested router-view

Tags: vue.js, key, css-transitions, vue-router

## What is expected

I have a tabbed navigation in one of my views which triggers nested `router-views` to be displayed. For these nested routes I want to apply a fade transition. I expect the transition to happen with `mode` `out-in`, so that the old `router-view` first fades out and then the new one fades in.

## What is happening

Only the *in* transition of the `out-in` `mode` works: When clicking on a navigation tab the old `router-view` disappears without transition, but the new one fades in as desired.

When I remove the `:key="$route.fullPath"` attribute of the parent `router-view` in `App.vue` (see below), the nested transitions work fine. But since I re-use router components I definitely need a `key` attribute on my outer `router-view`. 
 Also you should know that without the `appear` attribute and the `keep-alive` around the nested `router-view` no transition would happen at all. I adjusted my code so far according to this [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/router/issues/465) on GitHub. 
 How can I manage to both keep the `key` on the `router-view` in `App.vue` and make the transition in the nested view work?

#### App.vue

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <router-view :key="$route.fullPath" />
</div>
```

#### Profile.vue (where nested transitions should happen)

```
<div class="profile__main">
  <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
    <Transition name="fade" mode="out-in" appear>
      <keep-alive>
        <component :is="Component"></component>
      </keep-alive>
    </Transition>
  </router-view>
</div>

[...]

.fade-enter-from, .fade-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
}

.fade-leave-active {
    transition-duration: 500ms;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
}

.fade-enter-active {
    transition-duration: 300ms;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
}
```

#### router/index.js

```
{
    path: '/profile',
    name: 'Profile',
    component: Profile,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
      title: 'Your Profile',
    },

    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        name: 'ProfileOverview',
        component: ProfileOverview,
      },
      {
        path: 'settings',
        name: 'ProfileSettings',
        component: ProfileSettings,
        meta: {
          title: 'Your Profile Settings',
        },
      },
      {
        path: 'subscriptions',
        name: 'ProfileSubscriptions',
        component: ProfileSubscriptions,
        meta: {
          title: 'Your Subscriptions',
        },
      }]
  },
```

Comment: Did you managed to work this out?

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1):

I had similiar issue that could be related to yours. In my case I'm using `<Suspense>` with async pages/components and only out transition. So I wanted to keep old component visible until new one is ready, and then perform transition. Problem was that while using unique `key` on `<router-view>` old page was disappearing right away, then there was blank space (or specified Suspense fallback), and finally transition to new page started. Without `key` transition it was working like I wanted, so no blank/fallback between pages.

Anyway, I described this so someone could google it.

Quick solution is here: https://github.com/vuejs/router/issues/1175

So if we use component from slot, key should be on that component and not router view.

So try this:

```
<div class="profile__main">
  <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
    <Transition name="fade" mode="out-in" appear>
      <component :is="Component" :key="$route.fullPath"></component>
    </Transition>
  </router-view>
</div>
```